# selecting distinct ids from a table through hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the below pojo which contain many attributes and corresponding setters and getters

```
public class TOAAarty 
{

   protected long id;
   private long version;

   //corresponding setters and getters

   }
```

now i have fire the below query which bring distinct records from the data base

```
   select  distinct(id) from toa_arty  // so this query bring the distincr ids's
```

now in the similar fashion i want to rite HQL for this in hibernate to achieve the same as above query so what i have tried is  that basically there will be a method which will populate the list with the ids as output

so what i have tried is shown below please advise is it correct and is there any other better approach to achieve the same

```
    public List<Long> findDistinctRrokerIds()
    {
   Criteria query = session.createCriteria(TOAAarty.class);
   ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
   proList.add(Projections.property("id"));
   query.setProjection(Projections.distinct(proList));
   return (List<Long>) criteria.list(); query.list();
   }
```

Comment: sorry, why you have to check for distinct ID? the idea of using an ID is that should be unique so is pointless to use `distinct` ¿?...

Comment: well here id is our internal column it is not the unique one